# Regex to search and replace a string with variable index

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I need help to make a regex to find string like:

```
<?php if ($course['image']) { ?>
```

or

```
<?php if ($course['date']) { ?>
```

and replace with

```
{{$course->image}} or {{$course->date}} or {{$course->whateverindex}}
```

thanks!

Comment: 1) write a regex to match your first line, 2) replace `image` with a wildcard + repetition symbol, 3) group it, 4) reference the group in the target string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<\?php echo \$(\w+)\['(\w+)']; \?>
```

replace with

```
{{\$$1->$2}}
```

Comment: `<` is not a special `regex` character; it doesn't need to be escaped. The same for `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could find your lines with:

[`<\?php if \(\$course\[[^]]+]\) \{ \?>`](https://regex101.com/r/WyfTl3/1)

and replace with `{{\$course->image}}`

If you need to specify only `'image'` instead of matching all of them, you could replace `[^]]+` with `'image'` like:

`<\?php if \(\$course\['image']\) \{ \?>`